# Effect of slow/unstable network connection in JMETER

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmx, latency

Is network connection can affect the connection between servers and JMeter? Are there any way to reduced the number of error percentage and high average response time?

Answer (score 2):

Of course it can, looking into [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html):

> **Elapsed time**. JMeter measures the elapsed time from just before sending the request to just after the last response has been received. JMeter does not include the time needed to render the response, nor does JMeter process any client code, for example Javascript.
>
> **Latency**. JMeter measures the latency from just before sending the request to just after the first response has been received. Thus the time includes all the processing needed to assemble the request as well as assembling the first part of the response, which in general will be longer than one byte. Protocol analysers (such as Wireshark) measure the time when bytes are actually sent/received over the interface. The JMeter time should be closer to that which is experienced by a browser or other application client.
>
> **Connect Time**. JMeter measures the time it took to establish the connection, including SSL handshake. Note that connect time is not automatically subtracted from latency. In case of connection error, the metric will be equal to the time it took to face the error, for example in case of Timeout, it should be equal to connection timeout.

So the formula is:

```
Response time = Connect Time + Latency + actual server response time
```

If there are networking problems - it will have direct impact on the response time. Check out [How to Analyze the Results of a Load Test Using BlazeMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-analyze-results-load-test-using-blazemeter-0) article to see how networking issues affect test results. So if you want to get more "clear" picture it's recommended to have JMeter load generator(s) having direct access to the application under test, to wit use [LAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_area_network) instead of Wi-Fi, make sure that [NIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_interface_controller) cards (as well as routers/switches) have enough bandwidth to serve the anticipated data volumes.